# Is there a PHP 5.5 buildpack with APC (Alternative PHP Cache)?

Tags: php, laravel, ibm-cloud, apc

Can I use APC ([Alternative PHP Cache](http://php.net/manual/en/book.apc.php)) in my Bluemix PHP environment?

I added `{ "PHP_EXTENSIONS": ["apc"] }` to my `options.json` file but when I tried that to deploy a message said that apc wasn't included in the buildpack. I need `PHP 5.5` so I'm using `php-buildpack#v4.3.2`. Can you suggest a buildpack that includes APC?

I need an in-memory cache to replace Laravel's file cache. If I can't use APC, can anyone suggest anything else?

Comment: To close things out:

Comment: To close things out: I used php-buildpack#v4.1.5 which includes apc though it's based on PHP 5.4  so I had to down-level my guzzle to 5.3.0 which meant I needed to modify my guzzle code since I was using the guzzle 6 apis. I then changed my Laravel cache calls to use apc. Surprisingly, after all that the app still works, though whether it's really any faster is hard to tell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To close things out: I used php-buildpack#v4.1.5 which includes apc though it's based on PHP 5.4 so I had to down-level my guzzle to 5.3.0 which meant I needed to modify my guzzle code since I was using the guzzle 6 apis. I then changed my Laravel cache calls to use apc. Surprisingly, after all that the app still works, though whether it's really any faster is hard to tell

Answer (score 0):

The Bluemix default PHP buildpack, which is listed in the admin catalog, is v4.1.5. This version supports both PHP 5.5 and APC. So you can bring your local environment to be compatible with PHP buildpack 4.1.5 to develop app on this version of buildpack.

Comment: Thanks, @yingzhao. I tried that buildpack, and while it appears to include APC - it didn't complain when I included' "apcu", "apc"' in 'options.json' - it is based on PHP 5.4.45, not 5.5.

Answer (score 0):

PHP 5.5 and later come bundled with the OpCache, which supercedes the APC.

If you have code that uses the APC functions, you can continue using them in PHP 5.5 by using the APCu extension. APCu is APC, but with the opcache part removed (so that you can use the built-in OpCache instead), just leaving the memory cache and PHP functions to access it.

References:

- http://jessesnet.com/development-notes/2014/php-55-opcache-apcu/
- http://php.net/manual/en/migration55.new-features.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/book.apcu.php
- https://pecl.php.net/package/APCu

Comment: Thanks, Simba, but it's the application functions I need, not the opcache, and it still looks as though I'll need to install ACPu from PECL, and I don't know how to do that on Bluemix. Or am I mistaken, and can I just use APIs like acpu_add() without having to do anything?

Comment: When I said 'install' I meant compilation - all I see are the C source files. I don't have any compile facilities.

Comment: I'll be honest, I'm not familiar with Bluemix so my advice is more general PHP. However, a [quick bit of googling](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=php+apcu+on+bluemix) gave me [this page](https://developer.ibm.com/bluemix/2014/06/17/getting-started-laravel-bluemix/) which includes an answer that implies adding APCu is just a matter of including it in the Bluemix config file. Tha'ts the best I can do that since it's platform-specific on a platform I don't know, but other platforms I've worked with do provide APCu as an installable extension and I don't see why yours should be different.